# LaTeX / RMarkdown equation query

Tags: r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and R Markdown and am trying to recreate the following equation:

[image]

So far, I have the following:
[image]

My issue is getting the second line to appear inside the curly brackets (apologies for the screenshot, I can't get the code to align properly):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
   ... & ... \\
   ... & ... }
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

---

In general, there is a separate community for questions about LaTeX: [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, worked perfectly!  I hadn't realised about the separate LaTeX community so will go and visit now.